# Paste Image to Word-File from Variable not path in powershell - Alternative to AddPicture method

Tags: powershell

i wrote a script that reads multiple variables per System.Windows.Forms, copies a template of a *.doc file with bookmarks in it and loops through a for-loop to write multiple *.doc files filled with information entered in the form. Everything works fine, but one thing is bothering me:

One step of that loop contains pasting an image into that word file. You can choose an image file which is resized and shown in the form like that:

```
$img = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::Fromfile($pathFromForm)
[float]$imgprop= $img.Width/$img.Height
[int32]$imgWidth=70
[int32]$imgHeight=[math]::Round($imgWidth*$imgprop)
$imgResizedObj= New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($img,$imgHeight, $imgWidth)
$PreviewBox= new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PreviewBox.Image = $imgResizedObj
```

Now it is possible to add this image in a for-loop with

```
$docImg.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture($path)
```

but that means, that in each iteration the same file is selected and would be needed to be resized over and over, while i already have a resized image saved to a variable. Is it instead possible to insert $imgResizedObj in some way?

Tried to understand InlineShapes, but couldn't really find helpful information.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between the first snippet of code and the second? `$docImg` and `$path` are never used in the first snippet, so what do they have to do with it?

Comment: ```InlineShapes.AddPicture``` can only insert pictures from a file path - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture - you can’t insert a dotnet ```Bitmap``` object directly. You could save ```$ImgResizedObj``` to a temporary file and insert *that* into the Word document, but it might be better to just insert the raw image and resize the picture box depending on how much you care about file size vs image quality…

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen
This is not the whole code. The first part is a click event that happens when you chose a file via FileDialog. The Path is written in a Textbox and the image of the path is loaded, resized and put to a preview box on the form. The second code is part of a for loop that writes data to *.doc files.
@ mclayton: Yeah i thought so. I tried it by using a stream but i guess i'll have to use a temp file, because AddPicture isn't able to understand streams.

Comment: @gonzo0815 Yeah, but if you show us the full context we might be able to show you how to keep track of which images you've already resized so that you don't repeat the same code over and over again :)

Comment: The code opens a form where you enter some information and one image. This information is passed to a bunch of variables. After you entered all relevant information you click a button that starts a loop which generates a couple of *.doc-files filled with the information that is passed into the variables.

For the image a dialog box opens and you can chose a file that is resized to be previewed in the form. In that context the image is resized. The resized image is now saved to a temporary file, so when the loop to generate the *.doc files can access that image to insert it into each file.